# Changing flyout text in Layer panel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Is there a way of changing the text that is shown in the flyout when hovering over a layer name in the layer panel - where does that text come from?

Comment: the bit after the name?

Comment: You can add additional text by inserting it into the _Abstract_ section in the layer's properties.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Just to clarify: the information should be entered into the Abstract section under the "QGIS Server" section, not the "Metadata" section.

Comment: Further to this: the text is only permanent where a project is saved - is there a way of reproducing this to show irrespective of which project the layer is opened in?